# Get the changeset number of a triggered build in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Can someone please tell me how I can get the changeset number, the current build of TFS 2010 was triggered for?

I want to extend the build worklfow if the build was triggered by a checkin and want to do some more processing for which I need the changesetnumber of the changeset that was created by the checkin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Posted an answer using pure MSBuild here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748338/tf-exe-on-tfspreview/12923581

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the Solution. The Changesetnumber for which the build is triggered is populated in the Variable:
BuildDetail.SourceGetVersion

Comment: I see the reference info for this property. How can I access the sourcegetversion inside my C# code so I can compile the version# into the executable?

Answer (score 1):

Using an extension from http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/, you can do this with the TfsVersion task in the Build project:

```
   <MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Tfs.TfsVersion LocalPath="$(SolutionRoot)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Changeset" PropertyName="Revision" />
    </MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Tfs.TfsVersion>
```

Comment: Thx but I said that i want to extend the --> workflow <--. The time where I need the changesetnumber is within the phase where the workflow is not running on a selected agent.